# Getting single value from Dataframe Cell works with .loc but not with .at

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe that contains some dates and prices.
My Index contains the dates (attributed by df.set_index) and columns different assets.

It looks like something like this but is [6069 rows x 306 columns]

```py
            OVER_price  DI1J95_price
1995-01-02       48.61        45.662
1995-01-03       50.12        45.542
2019-03-11        6.40           NaN
```

I Have a class that takes as parameters calcDate that is the index date, diCode that is the asset name in the columns and diPanel that is my dataFrame.

If I run inside my class df.loc:

```py
#Find Prices     
self.diPrice = diPanel.loc[self.calcDate, self.diCode]
```

I get the expected price, no problems.

If I change the code to df.at:

```py
#Find Prices     
self.diPrice = diPanel.at[self.calcDate, self.diCode]
```

I get a KeyError exception. For instance 2019-03-11 as calcDate returns:

Exception has occurred: KeyError
17966

Any clues on what is going on?
Thanks

---

### Based on **Rich Andrews**' answer :

> What appears to be going on is that `.at` is having difficulty with the type of the index.

In fact the problem is the datetime type. Allmy code is based on `numpy.datetime64[D]` type. However my DataFrame's index is a `pandas.Timestamp`.

I was able tho double check that running:

```py
# Print last Index value and Type
print(type(diPanel.index[6068]))
print(diPanel.index[6068])
```

Returns:

```py
2019-03-11 00:00:00
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

And for my search argument:

```py
# Print last Index value and Type
print(type(self.calcDate))
print(self.calcDate)
```

Returns:

```py
<class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2019-03-11
```

For some reason `.loc` is able to bypass the type mismatch and `.at` isn't.
Have anyone had the same issue and knows why the two methods behave differently?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doc says `pandas.DataFrame.at` raises a `KeyError` when the label does not exist in the `DataFrame`.

This holds true when there is a type mismatch too.

What appears to be going on is that `.at` is having difficulty with the type of the index.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

csvdata = StringIO("""date,OVER_price,DI1J95_price
1995-01-02,48.61,45.662
1995-01-03,50.12,45.542
2019-03-11,6.40,""")

# index is a string
df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",", index_col="date")

# string being used
print(df.at['1995-01-03', 'OVER_price'])
```

Produces `50.12`.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

csvdata = StringIO("""date,OVER_price,DI1J95_price
1995-01-02,48.61,45.662
1995-01-03,50.12,45.542
2019-03-11,6.40,""")

# index is going to be a datetime
df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",", index_col="date", parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

# select with a datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
print(df.at[dt(year=1995, month=1, day=3), 'OVER_price'])
```

Produces `50.12`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your code works perfectly. Something is messing the data type on my df.at(). What puzzles me is why the df.loc() works and df.at does not. Theoretically, both should return error if there is a type mismatch right?

Comment: I don't know.  But it is a little surprising.  `at` returns a single value in a `Series` or `DataFrame` and can be precise while `loc` acts on groups of values and must be more loose on type conversion.  Would have to dive into the source!

Comment: Yes, I would guess `loc`and `at`would share a similar logic, but ´loc´ with the ability to have arrays as I/O. Guess I will take a look just out of curiosity.